# Combinatorics Proofcheck

Tags: combinatorics

> Integers $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5$  satisfy $1\leq a_1 <a_2 <a_3<a_4 <a_5\leq 20$, and any two number's difference is at least 3. How many possible sequences are there?

Let $d_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ and let $a_0=1, a_{6}=20$. Then we have
$$d_1+d_2+d_3+d_4+d_5+d_6=19.$$
Our constraints are $d_n \geq 3$ for $n \in {2,3,4,5}$, so let $d_n=d_n'+3$ for $n \in {2,3,4,5}.$
$$d_1+d_2'+d_3'+d_4'+d_5'+d_6=7$$
Which has $\dbinom{7+5}{5}=1287$ solutions through stars and bars. However, it doesn't agree with the answer key. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ve miscomputed $\binom{7+5}5.$

Specifically, we have $7+5=12,$ but the value you have is $\binom{13}5=1287.$

All the other steps look fine.

Comment: Uggggg, arithmetic problem.